How to use dsc properties for specific versions in puppet
I have a scenario where I have to use a specific property in a dsc resource in puppet for a specific version and not for other versions.
As $productbysa is needed only for version 2022 and not for other versions, also it is successful for 2022 but fails for older versions as "productbysa" is not recognized.
Looking for ideas/thoughts on how to execute this dsc resource only for 2022 version in puppet with $productbysa and for other versions it needs to be excluded
  if ($install_version == "2022") {
    $productbysa = $manage_productbysa
  }
  else {
    $productbysa = false
  }


  dsc { 'SQLServer':
    resource_name => 'SqlSetup',
    module        => 'SqlServerDsc',
    properties    => {
      action              => 'Install',
      instancename        => 'mssqlserver',
      sourcepath          => $path_sql_install_media,
      suppressreboot      => true,
      features            => $features,
      **productbysa**     => $**productbysa**,
      updateenabled       => 'False',
      sqmreporting        => 'False',
      errorreporting      => 'False',
      installshareddir    => $path_sql_install_shared,
      installsharedwowdir => $path_sql_install_shared_wow,
      instancedir         => $path_sql_instance,
      sqlsvcaccount       => {
        'dsc_type'       => 'MSFT_Credential',
        'dsc_properties' => {
          'user'     => "${domain_prefix}\\${service_acct_with_dollar}",
          'password' => Sensitive($credential_service_acct[password]),
        },
      },


You can use the + operator for hash merging:
if ($install_version == "2022") {
  $productbysa = { productbysa => $manage_productbysa }
}
else {
  $productbysa = {}
}

...

properties    => {
  action              => 'Install',
  instancename        => 'mssqlserver',
  sourcepath          => $path_sql_install_media,
  suppressreboot      => true,
  features            => $features,
  updateenabled       => 'False',
  sqmreporting        => 'False',
  errorreporting      => 'False',
  installshareddir    => $path_sql_install_shared,
  installsharedwowdir => $path_sql_install_shared_wow,
  instancedir         => $path_sql_instance,
  sqlsvcaccount       => {
    'dsc_type'       => 'MSFT_Credential',
    'dsc_properties' => {
      'user'     => "${domain_prefix}\\${service_acct_with_dollar}",
      'password' => Sensitive($credential_service_acct[password]),
    },
  },
} + $productbysa

Note you could also convert the first conditional into a selector:
$productbysa = $install_version ? {
  '2022'  => { productbysa => $manage_productbysa },
  default => {},
}


... and something along those lines is certainly what I would do, but there are also more brutish alternatives such as defining alternative values for the whole 'properties' hash in the conditional block.
